# PhoneGap + jqMobi List cannot scroll on Android

Tags: android, cordova, append, web-sql, jqmobi

When I get result from web sql DB and show them in the list, 
I face with the problem that I can't scroll on Android, by the way I am using cordova2.6.0.js with jqMobi and jqUI ; What I am trying to do is simply showing while appending new item on the list

```
<div id="firmList" class="panel" title="Firma">
   <div id="firmListInside" >
      <ul><li><a href="#firmID">Firma</a></li></ul>
      <ul><li><a href="#firmID">Firma</a></li></ul>
      <ul><li><a href="#firmID">Firma</a></li></ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

That code above is working fine and it is scrollable on both iOS and Android but when I tried with my result ;

```
$("#firmList").html('<div id="firmListInside"><ul></ul></div>');

for (var i=0; i< len; i++){
//some variable
$("#firmListInside > ul").append('<li><a href="#"'+myId+'>'+firmName+'></a></li> ');
}
```

When I execute it, that gives me the page with correct result but I cannot scroll it ! (ONLY ANDROID, on iOS same code working!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered this on github, but for anyone else.

You can not update a panel's HTM using $().html()  - this removes the scroller.  You must use $.ui.updateContentDiv  http://app-framework-software.intel.com/api/index.html#$.ui.updateContentDiv

```
$.ui.updateContentDiv("#firmList",'<div id="firmListInside"><ul></ul></div>');
```

Then you can access $("#firmListInside") no problem